# Showing updated plot at every step with matplotlib's plot_directive

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, python-sphinx

I am using Matplotlib's plot_directive Sphinx extension, and have something like:

```
.. plot::
   :context:
   :include-source:

    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
    [stuff here]

Text here

.. plot::
   :context:
   :include-source:

    ax.set_xlim(0., 100.)
    ax.set_ylim(0., 100.)
```

The issue is that the plot doesn't appear the second time around. The only way I can get another plot to appear is to instantiate a new `plt.figure()`. Is there a way to force the output plot to appear after the second `..plot` directive in the above example, without re-creating a new figure from scratch?

Comment: This only occurs when ``plot_apply_rcparams = True``. I'm suspecting that this may be a Matplotlib bug.